# how to show the tooltip with bootstrap 4 and angular 2?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, twitter-bootstrap-4

I want to show the tool-tip for input field based on the condition and here is the following code snippet I have used. i want to display tool-tip based on a specific variable.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control error-tooltip"
    focusFirst="false" ngbTooltip="{{error}}" 
    placement="bottom"
    triggers="manual" #t="ngbTooltip">
```

Answer (score 11):

in your Template:

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="name" placeholder="placeholder" ngbTooltip="tipContent" #t="ngbTooltip" >
```

in your controller:

```
@ViewChild('t') tooltip: NgbTooltip;
```

in your method to open, like submit :

```
this.tooltip.open();
```

make sure jo load the modules and import NgbTooltip

See example, Context and manual triggers, in the doc: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples

Answer (score 2):

In official docs;

> Tooltips can contain any arbitrary HTML, Angular bindings and even directives! Simply enclose desired content in a <**template**> element.

Example from [official site](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip);

```
<template #tipContent>Hello, <b>{{name}}</b>!</template>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" [ngbTooltip]="tipContent">
  I've got markup and bindings in my tooltip!
</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for response my question in i want show or hide tooltip based on a condition in controller.

Comment: Did you try `ngIf` in template to check error and then show it?

Answer (score 2):

Use  `ngbTooltip` for tooltip

Ex:

```
<i data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" ngbTooltip="your message">?</i>
```

Answer (score 2):

use 'disableTooltip', it takes a boolean value.

```
<label placement="top" [ngbTooltip]='Your message ' [disableTooltip]='Your condition' class="col-md-3">
```

I used on a label and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use Bootstrap 4 Tooltip

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" placement="top" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on top">
  Tooltip on top
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" placement="right" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on right">
  Tooltip on right
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" placement="bottom" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on bottom">
  Tooltip on bottom
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary mr-2" placement="left" ngbTooltip="Tooltip on left">
  Tooltip on left
</button>
```

[Angular Powered Bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tooltip/examples)